# nested websocket function always returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I'm using websockets from this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket

This is a function in React.ts 17 that successfully retrieves the data from the server, but fails to return the values of the function itself.

```
    const recieveMessages = () => {

        client.onmessage = (message: any) => {
            const dataFromServer = JSON.parse(message.data)
            console.log(dataFromServer) //This successfully logs the data
            return dataFromServer //This is always returned as undefined
        }
          //I've tried a few versions with the return statement here without any success.
    }
```

How can I make the **recieveMessages** function return the data from the **client.onmessage** function?

**Update:** I'm trying to seperate all the logic into a seperate React hook(useWebSocket) which currently looks like this:

```
import { w3cwebsocket } from 'websocket'

export const useWebSocket = () => {
    const client = new w3cwebsocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000')

    const connectToServer = () => {
        client.onopen = () => { console.log('Websocket client connected') }
    }

    const recieveMessages = () => {
        client.onmessage = (message: any) => {
            const dataFromServer = JSON.parse(message.data)
            console.log('reply from server: ', dataFromServer)
            return dataFromServer
        }
    }

    const sendMessage = (message: any) => {
        client.send(JSON.stringify('lol'))
    }
    const onCloseServer = (event: CloseEvent) => {
        console.log(event)
    }

    return {
        connectToServer,
        recieveMessages,
        sendMessage,
        onCloseServer
    }
}
```

I'm then trying to run the function inside the useEffect in a separate component like this:
The desire is to set the following data inside the local state of this component.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        recieveMessages()
        setState(recieveMessages()) //This is always undefined
    }, [])
```

Comment: You can't. Not without wrapping it in a Promise or callback, but that defeats the purpose of Web Sockets.  You'll have to handle the flow from within the `onmessage` function. Maybe you could share what you're trying to achieve with the sockets, because it feels like you're trying to find a solution for your solution instead of a solution for your problem.

Comment: As I though, could you possibly provide a example?

Comment: I'm trying to separate all the logic into a separate React hook(useWebSocket) and then call on the hook(useWebSocket)

Comment: Could you share what you've created thus far by editing your question?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Yes of course, please have a look.

Comment: You have no control when you receive the WebSocket messages, so explicitly calling a function to receive one makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls for a `useState` hook inside your `useWebSocket` hook.
Whenever `client.onmessage` receives a message, store that message inside of a state and update it every time another message is received.

Then return the state from the hook.

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { w3cwebsocket } from 'websocket'

export const useWebSocket = () => {
  const [receivedMessage, setReceivedMessage] = useState('')
  const client = new w3cwebsocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000')

  client.onmessage = (message: any) => {
    const dataFromServer = JSON.parse(message.data)
    setReceivedMessage(dataFromServer)
  }

  const sendMessage = (message: any) => {
    client.send(JSON.stringify(message))
  }

  return {
    receivedMessage,
    sendMessage,
  }
}
```

Then implement it like so. The `receivedMessage` value is the state that will be updated and can be monitered with a `useEffect` hook to do something whenever a message has been received.

```
const { receivedMessage, sendMessage } = useWebSocket()

useEffect(() => {
  if (receivedMessage !== '') {
    // Do something whenever the received message is changed.
    sendMessage('Received you loud and clear')
  }
}, [receivedMessage])
```